# HATEOAS and discovery for existing resources

Tags: api, rest, hateoas

What is HATEOAS way of discovering existing resources? Let's say I have a collection of resources and normally client first gets the list of resources and then it can navigate to each resource from the list, because server provides information how to get each resource. But what if client needs to get particular resource directly without fetching list first?

An example could be a web application that has a page with list of items (for example users) `/api/users` and user can navigate to user page where client fetch single user `/api/users/1234`. Frontend app has its own routing and user page can have following URL `https://example.com/users/1234/details`). Now imagine that client opens user page directly, how it can know which endpoint to use to get user data from the server?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are conflating two different levels of interaction:

- The user interacting with a front-end application
- The front-end application interacting with an API

The front-end application might provide a page per user, a summary page for a group of users, or embed the user information in a widget on every page's header.

The API, on the other hand, might provide an end-point to list groups, one to list users in a group, one to get details of a particular user, etc. HATEOAS is talking about how an API client would discover these.

So in your scenario, it might look like this:

- The user requests `https://example.com/users/1234/details`
- The front-end application on `https://example.com` will have an internal function to fetch the user details for ID `1234`
- This will require multiple calls to the API, some of which may be loaded from a cache, e.g.:

  1. `GET /users/` or `GET /users/?filter=id:1234` - retrieve a list of zero or more user records
  2. If there are no results, or the results don't include the selected user, abort with an error
  3. Parse the user record for user ID `1234` and extract a link to the related user details resource
  4. `GET` the resource indicated by that link
- The parsed result of that final API call is what will be returned by the internal function, and ultimately displayed to the user

Comment: Be careful navigating to an individual entity via a list. It is only practical when the list is likely to be small. The response from `/users` could be thousands or in fact millions of results. In situations like this is might be more practical to offer a search.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that was actually my question - what is the best way to get the endpoint for user details. It gives an idea of `HEAD /users?id=1234` that returns link to user resource. But I am wondering what is the best response if user does not exist. Return 200 and `Link: null`? Using it just as a "link builder" (only provide a link and do not check if user exists) would probably violate HTTP spec since response headers for `HEAD` should be the same as for `GET`.

Comment: @rkm If you're directly loading `/users?id=1234` intending it to return a single user record, you're already not doing HATEOAS, because you're assuming a particular link structure. You need either a list or, as Qwerky says, a search, which could return zero results if there was no such user.

Comment: I meant the way to filter `/users` collection. It will return either empty list or list with one element in this case. This is similar to what @Qwerky suggested, but without introducing a separate `search`. In my cases list of resources is not expected to be big (up to 1K items)

Comment: @rkm I'm confused then, why would that be a `HEAD` request? Just `GET` the filtered list, and the response body will contain zero or more user records, each with links to end-points for retrieving other data related to that user.

Comment: I think you are right, it should be `GET`. Initially I was thinking about using `HEAD` only to build links without actually checking if data is in the database. I mean that `HEAD` could just provide a link to a user, but then calling that link with `GET` might return 404 and it seems to violate HTTP spec.

Comment: @rkm I think my more fundamental question is why that link would ever be in the response _headers_, rather than part of the returned entity. Such a link header would have to declare some relationship to _the whole of_ the requested entity, but the requested entity is a collection not an item, so the relationship would have to be something like "details of first/only user in this filtered list". It makes much more sense for a "details of this user" link to be attached to a summary record of the user returned as part of the response.